# How do you force a process to become the parent process of another application?

Tags: cygwin, process, debugger

I am using cygwin and writing a debugger, and I found this question worthy of superuser.  I am trying to make my program insert itself above another on the process tree, without ptrace, as it is not implemented.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: Cygwin suggests it's Windows at the base . . . though this is likely a question better suited for SO than SuperUser . . .